# Lucene.net - TopDocs missing totalHits?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, lucene, lucene.net

I downloaded Lucene.net 2.9.4.1 using NuGet Package Manager and used the following code to create a test index:

```
Dim sysDir As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/index"))
Dim indexDir As Store.Directory = Store.FSDirectory.Open(sysDir)
Dim analyzer As Analysis.Analyzer = New Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer(Util.Version.LUCENE_29)
Dim indexWriter As Index.IndexWriter = New Index.IndexWriter(indexDir, analyzer, True, Index.IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED)

Dim doc As Documents.Document = New Documents.Document()
Dim fldContent As Documents.Field = New Documents.Field("content", "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", Documents.Field.Store.YES, Documents.Field.Index.ANALYZED, Documents.Field.TermVector.YES)
doc.Add(fldContent)

indexWriter.AddDocument(doc)
indexWriter.Optimize()

indexWriter.Close()
indexDir.Close()
```

Next, when I got to writing code for carrying out a search, I can't access the totalHits property of TopDocs class. Here's the code:

```
Dim sysDir As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/index"))
Dim indexDir As Store.Directory = Store.FSDirectory.Open(sysDir)
Dim searcher As Search.IndexSearcher = New Search.IndexSearcher(indexDir, True)

Dim searchTerm As Index.Term = New Index.Term("content", "fox")
Dim query As Search.Query = New Search.TermQuery(searchTerm)
Dim tdocs As Search.TopDocs = searcher.Search(query, Nothing, 100)
```

When I type "tdocs" followed by a dot on the next line, I can only access GetMaxScore and SetMaxScore methods and MaxScore property - I don't see any property that says "totalHits".

Am I missing something? Does anyone have some sample code where they're using Lucene.net.Search.TopDocs instead of Lucene.net.Search.Hits (which is said to be obsolete).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you use VB, currently Lucene is not CLS compliant.

I **think** it has something to do with that bug which will be fixed in next release.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENENET-476

Comment: You're right, I updated manually to Lucene.net 2.9.4g and was able to get the topDocs class working.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the sample C# code:

```
TopDocs topDocs = searcher.Search(query, luceneHitsLimit);
if (topDocs != null) {
    int totalResults = topDocs.totalHits;
    ScoreDoc[] scoreDocs = topDocs.scoreDocs;
    foreach(ScoreDoc scoreDoc in scoreDocs) {
        Document doc = searcher.Doc(scoreDoc.doc);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If you're able to access totalHits property, can you please tell me which version of Lucene.net assembly are you using? Did you add it using NuGet?

Comment: I'm currently using Lucene.Net 2.9.2.1 Didn't add it via NuGet, just downloaded the source, built it and added the dll.

Answer (score 0):

*I know this is probably a little late, but hopefully it can help you or someone else in the future.*

To work around the issue in 2.9.4, I edited the source in the TopDocs class.  The reason it doesn't work is that VB is not case sensitive whereas C# is (as we all know).

The TopDocs class has a totalHits int property and a TotalHits int property.  After looking at the code, I realized that the TotalHits property just gets/sets the totalHits variable.  So I just changed the totalHits variable's name to totalHits_obsolete within the class and then rebuilt the library.

As soon as it built, my other project was able to access the TotalHits property from my VB.Net code.